# How to delete from table where duplicate count is greater than but keep one

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete rows from a table which has count of columns equals to 'REG' greater than one of count of columns equals to 'UNREG'. but keep last one.

```
table
+------+------+--------+
| id   | name | status |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 | sa   | REG    |
|    2 | sam  | UNREG  |
|    3 | sa   | UNREG  |
|    4 | sam  | REG    |
|    5 | sak  | UNREG  |
|    6 | sak  | REG    |
|    7 | saa  | UNREG  |
|    8 | saa  | REG    |
|    9 | sam  | REG    |
|   10 | sa   | REG    |
+------+------+--------+


 DELETE n1 FROM names n1, names n2 
 WHERE n1.id > n2.id 
 AND count(case when n1.status = 'REG' then 1 end) > count(case when 
 n2.status = 'UNREG' then 1 end);
```

this query returns an error of

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

after the query it should be

```
 +------+------+--------+
 | id   | name | status |
 +------+------+--------+
 |    1 | sa   | REG    |
 |    2 | sam  | UNREG  |
 |    3 | sa   | UNREG  |
 |    4 | sam  | REG    |
 |    5 | sak  | UNREG  |
 |    6 | sak  | REG    |
 |    7 | saa  | UNREG  |
 |    8 | saa  | REG    |
 +------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Keep last one of what?  I don't follow what you want to delete and what you want to keep?

Comment: keep one row contains 'REG' of the selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution that simply self-joins the table and avoids the need for a potentially expensive aggregation.

```
delete n1 
from names n1
inner join names n2 
    on  n2.id < n1.id 
    and n2.name = n1.name 
    and n2.status = 'REG'
where n1.status = 'REG';
```

The self-`inner join` filters on records for which a record with the same name and a smaller `id` exists.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f4b1b0a501776fcbde496209c9da5aef)**:

Sample data:

```
id | name | status
-: | :--- | :-----
 1 | sa   | REG   
 2 | sam  | UNREG 
 3 | sa   | UNREG 
 4 | sam  | REG   
 5 | sak  | UNREG 
 6 | sak  | REG   
 7 | saa  | UNREG 
 8 | saa  | REG   
 9 | sam  | REG   
10 | sa   | REG
```

Table content after the query was executed:

```
id | name | status
-: | :--- | :-----
 1 | sa   | REG   
 2 | sam  | UNREG 
 3 | sa   | UNREG 
 4 | sam  | REG   
 5 | sak  | UNREG 
 6 | sak  | REG   
 7 | saa  | UNREG 
 8 | saa  | REG
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to delete all the `'REG'` rows which are not the lowest `id`.  For that:

```
delete n
    from names n join
         (select n.name, min(id) as min_id
          from names n
          where status = 'REG'
          group by n.name
         ) nn
         on n.name = nn.name and n.id > nn.min_id
    where n.status = 'REG';
```

Comment: ohh, it wiorked! this is what i've been looking for, thank you very much!